# Hibernate: Can we have a relationship between Entities in which both are owning-side?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, one-to-one

I am learning Hibernate and came across the terms `Owning-side` and `Non-owing side`.

Upon reading, I came to know that `Owning-side` means the Entity who has `FK` reference to the other Entity.

## Consider the below scenario:

## User entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn("VEHICLE_ID")
    private Vehicle vehicle;
    // other code
 }
```

## Vehicle Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle{
    @Id
    private int vehicleId;
    private String vehicleName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn("USER_ID")
    private User user;
    // other code
 }
```

If I keep the @JoinColumn in both these Entities, then would both these entities `User` and `Vehicle` become `owning-side` entities?

I am not able to understand as to why just placing `@JoinColumn` annotation makes an entity as the `owning-side` Entity.

Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: because as you said the one holding the fk reference is the owning side.
The join column is used to sepcify the presence of an Fk on that table, so effectively making it the owning side

Answer (score 1):

> If I keep the @JoinColumn in both these Entities, then would both
>   these entities User and Vehicle become owning-side entities?

We don't start with using the `@JoinColumn` in an entity and then state that particular entity is an owning entity. In fact the reverse is true.
We first decide which should entity should be owning entity and which one should be non-owning.
And we decide that by looking at which entity has the Foreign Key reference. And this again is more of a design choice. The one having the foreign-key reference is said to be the **owning entity**.
We then use the `@JoinColumn` annottation in the owning entity to specify the foreign key.
And in the non-owning side, we use `mappedBy` attribute inside of the particular association type.

In your example you are specifying a bi-directional relationship. So if we  consider Vehicle entity has the **foreignKey** as `userId`, then Vehicle entity would be our owning-entity and we annotate this 'userId' with '@JoinColumn'.
 And in the non-owning entity i.e. User entity, we would use the 'mappedBy' attribute to refer to the field in owning entity on which `@JoinColumn` has been used :

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
    private Vehicle vehicle;
    // other code
 }


@Entity
public class Vehicle{
    @Id
    private int vehicleId;
    private String vehicleName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn("USER_ID")
    private User user;
    // other code
 }
```

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/) is a detailed documentation that might help you as a reference :

The JPA API reference docs also provide a nice brief description for the different association types : [OneToOne](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) , [OneTomany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)  , [ManyToMany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html)